# Query to list users based on condition AND order by count of other condition

Tags: mysql, sql, count, relationship

Well, maybe the title is a bit unclear, but I'm trying to order a set of people based on their geographical area *AND* the amount of work they're charged with (i.e. the number of projects they're working on that meet some conditions).

For this task I'm making use of 5 tables (I'll write only the relevant columns):

```
users
-------------------------------
ID(PK) | first_name | last_name

users_data
----------------------------------
ID(PK) | user_id(FK) | area_id(FK)

projects
---------------------
ID(PK) | agent_id(FK)

states (working phases)
-------------
ID(PK) | name

projects_states (relation table)
------------------------------------------------------------
ID(PK) | project_id(FK) | state_id(FK) | created_ad (TSTAMP)
```

**In words:** I need all the agents (agent_id) who lives in a particular area (area_id), and I need this list to be ordered by number of projects (ASC), but I need to take into consideration (for the count) only those projects wich fall into a set of states (e.g, "open", "in progress", and so on).

*Example output:*

```
[firstName] [lastName] [projectNo]
  Agent      Six        (0)
  Agent      One        (0)
  Agent      Three      (1)
  Agent      Two        (3)
  Agent      Four       (4)
```

I tried with this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(p.id) AS projectNo, u.*,
   (SELECT ps.state_id FROM project_states ps WHERE ps.project_id = p.id
    ORDER BY ps.created_at DESC LIMIT 1) AS last_state
FROM users u
JOIN users_data ud ON ud.user_id = u.id
JOIN projects p ON p.agent_id = u.id
WHERE ud.area_id = 1
GROUP BY u.id
HAVING last_state IN (4,5,6,7)
ORDER BY projectNo DESC
```

The query works, but of course fetches only the (very limited) number of users who have a project in that range of state. If I remove the `HAVING` part I get all the users (that's what I want) but produces a wrong count, since it should not count the project who are assigned to that user but are outside the range of states, i.e. if the project is in state_id 8, it needs not be counted.

I feel I'm missing something obvious, but I've been trying for sometime and can't wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you do this with a subquery.  I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT sum(last_state IN (4,5,6,7)) as NumProjects, u.*
FROM (SELECT u.*,
             (SELECT ps.state_id
              FROM project_states ps
              WHERE ps.project_id = p.id
              ORDER BY ps.created_at DESC
              LIMIT 1
             ) AS last_state
      FROM users u JOIN
           users_data ud
           ON ud.user_id = u.id LEFT JOIN
           projects p
           ON p.agent_id = u.id
      WHERE ud.area_id = 1
     ) u
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY NumProjects DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you! If I change your query to `LEFT JOIN projects p ON p.agent_id = u.id` it seems to give me the expected results (not all users have a project associated, at least at this stage of development, I believe a Left join takes this into account)

Comment: @DamienPirsy . . . Yes, a left join solves that problem.